# Coding for Motorola RFID reader adapter for Rifidi Edge Server 3.3 issue in adding tags to ReadCycle

Tags: java, middleware, rfid, osgi-bundle, motorola

**I am developing Motorola RFID reader adapter for Rifidi Edge Server 3.3 taking reference of already available Rifidi CSL Reader Adapter.
Similar to CslRfidTagServer.java class of CSL Reader Adapter I have created MotoRfidTagServer.java in my adapter in which I am continuously recieving tags from physical motorola reader. I am adding all there tags to ReadCycle But I am getting only single tag in my Readzonesubscriber class of my Rifidi Application not all tags. Please provide some solution for this.**

My Sensor session class is as follows :

```
public class MotoSocketSensorSession extends AbstractServerSocketSensorSession {
    .......
    .......

public void sendTag(byte[] message) {

    String s = new String(message);
    System.out.println("tags--------------------------"+s);
    **// Getting each tags here**

    TagReadEvent event = this.tagHandler.parseTag(new String(message));
    Set<TagReadEvent> tres = new HashSet<TagReadEvent>();
    tres.add(event);

ReadCycle cycle = new ReadCycle(tres, readerID,System.currentTimeMillis());

    this.getSensor().send(cycle);

   }

private class MotoSocketMessageProcessingStrategy implements
        MessageProcessingStrategy {

    private MotoSocketSensorSession session = null;

    public MotoSocketMessageProcessingStrategy(MotoSocketSensorSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }


    @Override
    public void processMessage(byte[] message) {

        this.session.sendTag(message);
    }
}
    .......
    .......
    }
```

My ReadZoneSubscriber of my Rifidi application is as follows :

```
 public class AtsReadZoneSubscriber implements ReadZoneSubscriber {

    @Override
    public void tagArrived(TagReadEvent tag) {

System.out.println("TAG ARRIVED ->: " + tag.getTag().getFormattedID() + "At ReaderId:  "+tag.getReaderID()+"   from antenna: " + tag.getAntennaID());

  **//I am getting only single tag here only at once**
     }
 ..........
 ..........
  }
```

Comment: How did you set up the air interface of the RFID reading (session, target flipping)? It might be that that is a reason that a tag was only read once.

Comment: Thanks Danny, There was no issue with the air interface. The actual issue is resolved, the problem was there in creating TagReadEvent object.